# How do I target the PHP passed context node in XSLT?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, domdocument

The [`XSLTProcessor`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php)
 [`transformToDoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtodoc.php) method takes a `DOMNode` for parameter. So I thought I could load a `DOMDocument`, get a node from it (e.g. via `DOMXPath`), and then pass that to the XSLT to transform only that node and ignore (i.e. not output) anything else. But... how do I target that node? Is there even a way, or have I misunderstood how this works?

A `<xsl:template match="/">` matches the root node of the document (even though I pass in a child node), `<xsl:template match=".">` makes the thing crash, `<xsl:template match="name-of-passed-node">` does match, but everything "above" it is passed out as text (like the default xsl does)...

I.e. given this PHP:

```
// Load input document
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('some.xml');

// Find the context node we want to transform
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//some-node')->item(0);

// Load XSLT document
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('some.xsl');

// Do transformation
$x = new XSLTProcessor();
$x->importStylesheet($xsl);
$result = $x->transformToDoc($node);
```

How do I target the given node in my XSLT, so that I output and transform only *that* node and its descendants?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="   ?   ">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some tests I have run it seems that parameter is not designed to take in an arbitrary DOM node as the initial match, it seems to run the stylesheet on the ownerDocument of the DOM node. For instance, when you create new node not inserted at all in the document with e.g. `$doc->createElement('foo')` and pass it in to the transform methods, the `$doc` owner document is transformed. So I think the PHP guys modelled the XSLTProcessor API a bit after the original client-side Mozilla XSLTProcessor API but the argument you pass to the transform methods is treated much different to that API.

The only option I see in PHP is, if your stylesheet doesn't need to navigate outside of the node you want to pass in, to create a dummy doc with a clone

```
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->appendChild($doc2->importNode($node, TRUE));
```

and then pass that dummy doc to the transform method.

Comment: Ah, too bad.  Oh well, the dummy doc workaround looks like an OK solution, so I'll just add that to my Xslt helper class. Thanks! 